# Shell Script to create Directory with passwords and make it runnable in system startup

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, startup

What I have to do is to run a application on startup.  So I made it as a service.  ie as a shell script under /etc/init.d .  I am using Ubuntu.. The problem is I have to create a folder under /var/run directory if it does not exist.  Following is my code.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

start() {


if [ -d "/var/run/bucardo" ]; then
    echo "Directory Exists" 
    echo -n "Starting bucardo: "
    sudo bucardo_ctl start 
    echo "done."
else
    echo "Creating Directory" 
    sudo mkdir /var/run/bucardo
    echo -n "Starting bucardo: "
    sudo bucardo_ctl start 
    echo "done."
fi
}

stop() {
echo -n "Shutting down bucardo: "
sudo bucardo_ctl stop
echo "done."
}
case "$1" in
start)
start
;;
stop)
stop
;;
restart)
stop
sleep 10
start
;;
*)

esac
exit 0
```

SO to create a folder under /var/run which is the default folder for the application.

How can I create a folder with password in shell script.  So that I can check for folder and create it.

Following is the error I am getting when I made script run in startup.  I used the following command to do it "chkconfig --level 234 bocardo"

Following is the error..

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01centrifyda' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K01cups' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K01acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bucardo' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hwclock-save' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `hwclock-save'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `hwclock-save'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'ufw' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `ufw'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `ufw'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'lightdm' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `lightdm'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `lightdm'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'acpid' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `acpid'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `acpid'
insserv: warning: script 'centrifyda' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'adnisd' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-splash' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-splash'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-splash'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-interface' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `network-interface'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `network-interface'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-log' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-log'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-log'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'alsa-restore' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `alsa-restore'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `alsa-restore'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'procps' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `procps'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `procps'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udevtrigger' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udevtrigger'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udevtrigger'
insserv: warning: script 'cups' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'setvtrgb' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `setvtrgb'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `setvtrgb'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udev' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udev'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udev'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
```

and very long...  Please help me..
Thanks in advance..

As per Pieter's suggestion.. 
Following is the link to make it as a service in Ubentu.. http://jonathonhill.net/2009-04-23/auto-start-a-shell-script-on-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Any one who down vote please tell me the reason so tht I can correct next time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what the problem actually is.  Is it that `sudo mkdir` asks for a password?
Init scripts generally need to run as root already (and will during normal boot), so you don't want `sudo` in your script at all.  While testing, just `sudo` when you run the script.

Also, consider collapsing the directory existence conditional, and just use `mkdir -p`, which will not error if the directory already exists.

Comment: Thank you.. actually I want to run the script in system startup.  so is it possible to run a script with sudo in system startup?

Comment: As I said in my answer, init scripts run as root during normal boot.  No sudo necessary.  The sudo when you run it yourself for testing just simulates the permissions it will have when running at boot time.

Comment: Actually I just found out.. my script is not executing in starup..I typed following command  chkconfig --level 234 bocardo on to make the service as startup.  It is giving me error.  Is there any other way to make the bocardo service to launch in starup.  In Ubuntu?

Comment: Hay thank you..  what command should I use to do this..  I am new to ubuntu..  I will try tomorrow and let you know.. thanks once again..

Comment: @DilipRajkumar: You will probably need to add some required header comments to your script. See other scripts in `/etc/init.d` to use as models. That's what "LSB tags and overrides" refers to.

Comment: Thanks Pieter it worked.. great... instead of chkconfig I used update-rc.d and it worked great.  Thanks again..

Comment: Thanks @DennisWilliamson I used update-rc.d and it worked great.. thanks for your help..